# How to echo result of mysql_query

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

I have the code below; it works fine.

```
if($mball14 != '') {
    $qry = "SELECT * FROM manager WHERE mball14 IN(mball14, mball15, mball16, mball17, mball18, mball19, mball20)";
    $result = mysql_query($qry);
    if($result) {
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            $errmsg_arr[] = "<font color='#FF0000'>This Winning ID $mball14 has been paid on DATE. You cannot pay twice.</font>";
            $errflag = true;
        }
        @mysql_free_result($result);
    }
    else {
        die('Query failed0: ' . mysql_error());
    }
}
```

I want to find the date where "mball14" occurred and `echo` it in the error message along with the value of `$mball14`.
The date column is "mydate".

How do I get the `date` value from the mySQL result, in order to use it in the error message?

I have tried to make two queries but it does not work.

Comment: What is `mball14` , `mball15` ... ??

Comment: Sounds like the structure of the database makes this hard to work with. Many columns with the same name? That should ring an alarm-bell

Comment: @NanaPartykar mball14 is a column.

Comment: In what column in your DB is `DATE`? If your query for `*` is only to retrieve the date, can it not be simply reduced to fetch only that data? What is `$qry1`?

Comment: @Qirel, no column has the same name in the database...the number in front of each differentiates them.

Comment: @FredGandt, the column is mydate.

Comment: I haven't done SQL for years, so am not answering, but wouldn't `"SELECT mydate FROM manager WHERE mball14 IN(mball14, mball15, mball16, mball17, mball18, mball19, mball20)"` work?

Comment: @FredGandt, i was able to do that, but how do i echo it in the error message where i wrote DATE.

Comment: Ah! I see. You want to know how to extract the data from the query result?

Comment: @FredGandt, exactly.

Comment: See [`mysql_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php) documentation. And BTW: See warning about deprecation at the top of the page.

Comment: Exactly my point @jossyo - if you have many columns with the same name (but just a number that increments), that's a good indicator that the structure isn't good - at all ;-) you should separate it into a different table and reference an ID.

Comment: Warning: The functions named `mysql_xxx()` are deprecated and have been removed from recent PHP versions. At this stage, you should not be using them. Please update your code to use the equivalent `myslqi_xxx()` functions or the PDO library.

Answer (score 1):

use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` or `mysql_fetch_array()` to fetch the result of a query. Like below:

```
$res = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); //or mysql_fetch_array($result)[Search the difference b/w them and use accordingly]

echo $res['myDate']; // you will get your date.
```

if `echo` doesn't work which I think will work, use `print_r()`.

Comment: This is the correct answer for the `mysql_query()` in the question. However it is important to point out that the `mysql_xxx()` functions are deprecated and should not be used any more.

Comment: Yes, you're right,  thank you. He can convert it whole to the  `mysqli_xxx`.